# How to use .graphqls files in a Node application?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm attempting to refactor my Node-based Apollo GraphQL server instance to use .graphqls schema files instead of being string-based. I'm attempting to go by the example [here](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-fullstack-starter-kit/blob/master/src/server/api/schema.js) to **include** the files in my schema:

```
import facility_schema from './facility-objects.graphqls';
```

however, I get a *SyntaxError* from the import. This happens if I just run either **node** or **babel-node**. However, running this sample project on GitHub, it appears to work.

Am I missing a package? Am I using the wrong interpreter? I know I'm missing something, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For plain Node/Apollo, the following worked for me (with `babel-node`):

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
const schema = readFileSync(__dirname + '/schema.graphqls', 'utf8')
```

For Meteor/Apollo, you can try using the following new plugin (didn't try it myself, though):

https://github.com/Swydo/meteor-graphql

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wound up figuring out on my own. Apparently the project I was looking at was using webpack to bundle those files in as raw strings. Since that was all that it was doing, I could just do the same thing as readFileSync.